# Finding the point on $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+1}$ where the tangent line is perpendicular to $3x + y = 5$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$f(x)=\sqrt{2x+1}$$
>   Find the point on the radical function where the tangent line is perpendicular to
>   $3x + y = 5$.

I worked out the $y= -3x+5$, and therefore the slope was $-3$. I then used the negative reciprocal to find the slope of a perpendicular line, $m= 1/3$. I set the derivative equal to $1/3$ to find $x$ which I found to be $4$, $x=4$. I then put $x=4$ back into the original equation, and found the $y=3$ when $x$ is $4$.

Using the slope I had, and the point $(4,3)$, I inserted these numbers in the equation $y=mx+b$, to find that $b= 5/3$. So my final equation was $y=\frac13x+\frac53$. I put this and $y= -3x+5$ into my graphing calculator. The lines are not perpendicular to each other. I am not sure what I did wrong.

If someone could assist me that would be awesome.

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? You put two lines into your graphing calculator .... So? Why does that mean something is wrong?

Comment: After finding the point (4,3) you don't need to do anything. It's done!

Comment: your solution is ok (though the presentation lacks a little mathjaxing), and I thus give you a point for showing your work.

Answer (score 2):

You've found the line perpendicular to $y=-3x+5$,i.e $y=\frac{x}{3}+\frac{5}{3}$, which is tangential to $y=f(x)=\sqrt{2x+1}$. Now all you need to do is find the point where  $y=\sqrt{2x+1}$ and $y=\frac{x}{3}+\frac{5}{3}$ intersect. So in other word you have to solve $\frac{x}{3}+\frac{5}{3}$=$\sqrt{2x+1}$ for $x\ge 0$ and find the correspoding value of y. You should get $(x,y)=(4,3)$. (Of course you've already found this point since the radical function has gradient $\frac{1}{3}$ when x=4)